# Libraries internally being used by my (non-Android) library not getting included in classes.dex

Tags: android, android-build

This one has me stumped. I'm clearly missing something, but I can't figure out what.

I have a library (not an Android library - just a regular Java library project), which in turn uses other libraries. So, the setup is:

```
myApi.jar

   |
   +-- com/myapi/ ... (.class files here).
   | 
   +-- libs/
        |
        +-- lib1.jar
        +-- lib2.jar
```

Now, when I include `myApi.jar` in a project in the libs directory of an Android project, like `MyAndroidProject/libs`, only the `com.myapi. ...` classes are getting included in the `classes.dex` file. The classes from the lib1.jar and lib2.jar are not included in classes.dex

The obvious work-around is to remove the lib1.jar and lib2.jar from the myApi.jar file; and instead place them in `MyAndroidProject/libs` too. However, this means the users of myApi now have to know that there are additional JAR files to be placed on the build path. This is something I am looking to avoid.

So, is there anything special I need to do to include JAR files being used internally by a library JAR in the `classes.dex` file?

Comment: Why is this getting a downvote? Perfectly valid and clear question with details imho.

Comment: I noticed a downvote.I dont mind as long as the down-voter also explains the reason!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, this means the users of myApi now have to know that there are additional JAR files to be placed on the build path. This is something I am looking to avoid.

Here, Android's behavior is identical to ordinary Java's -- if `myApi.jar` were in support of a Swing app, you would need to either distribute all the JARs or merge all the JARs into one. Same thing with Android. You are welcome to fold all the classes from the dependent JARs into your own, or have projects reusing your JAR also add your dependencies as their own dependencies.

Note that merging JAR contents may have technical or licensing impacts, so make sure this is something you really want to do.

Comment: By "folding" all the classes into my JAR, do you mean copying the classes from the dependent JARs into the root of my own JAR?

Comment: @techie.curious: Yes. Basically, the combined JAR would contain the combined contents of all the JARs. JTwitter used to do this, for example -- it combined its own code with the `org.json` JAR, presumably for convenience. You may run into technical problems with duplicates (e.g., `MANIFEST.MF`). Note that, if we're really lucky, once we can package true Android library projects as JARs (R16 tools, maybe), perhaps it will do this sort of dependent JAR merging for us. Personally, right now, I'd just distribute the dependencies separately, as that's fairly typical in traditional Java development.

Comment: Thanks yet again @CommonsWare . I'll go ahead with your suggestion - distributing (or pointing to), the dependent library JARs. In any case the dependencies are standard ones (SimpleXML and Gson), so that hopefully reduces the hassle for the developer using my API.